# To ::close() or to ::fclose()?

Tags: c++, boost

We see a strange issue sometimes when we call `boost::filesystem::copy()` to copy a file from a normal local partition to one hosted on Lustre. Normally if we do `cp` of files we notice that the destination file exists correctly and is available immediately after `cp` returns, however with the boost operation, when it returns, the file may be all there or not (at the destination.)

Looking through the boost code, I see:

```
    if ( ::close( infile) < 0 ) sz_read = -1;
    if ( ::close( outfile) < 0 ) sz_read = -1;
```

I'm wondering if this is correct, will this correctly flush the file to the destination, or should this call `::fclose()` to explicitly flush and then close the file? I don't see any explicit `::fflush()` calls preceding the close, so not sure if the file really is flushed to the destination correctly...

Comment: `close` is not the same as `fclose`. Those are for different types of files (file descriptors versus stdio file handles).

Comment: `close(file descriptor)` and `fclose(file stream)` both are quit different. file descriptor is `int` type. file stream is `FILE *` type. we will use either open and close or  fopen and fclose

Comment: ...aww crap... schoolboy error! :{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the file was opened.  If it was opened with
the OS specific `::open`, then it must be closed with the OS
specific `::close`.  If it was opened with `fopen`, then it must
be closed with `fclose`.  And if it was opened with
`std::fstream::open` (or the constructor of an `fstream`), then
it must be closed by calling `close` on the object.

Boost is apparently using the low-level system calls.  In this
case, there is no buffer which needs flushing.  For `fclose` or
`fstream::close`, the close will flush the buffer automatically.
No explicit flush is needed.

Comment: ... <hangs head in shame/>... okay, still have to figure out why the copied file is not present then.. :/